# how to judge a page edited or not from server client

Tags: asp.net

a input asp.net page,you can image many input fields and a button named submit on it. 
before user submit the page ,I want to  compare all the fields values with default values . if anyting didn't change ,i will give him a message.
here it is the question:
 how to judge a page edited or not from server client(in button click event)?
i don't want compare each field in page.

Comment: what do you mean by 'i don't want compare each field in page'?

Comment: because there are too many fields.and i feel it's stupid.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, it's pretty straight forward:

```
$(RELEVANT_FORM).submit(function(){
    var Proceed=false;
    $(this).find('input').each(function(i,E){
        Proceed=Proceed || $(E).val()!=$(E).attr('defaultValue');
    });
    if(!Proceed){alert('You havent done anything');return false;}
    return true;
});
```